# Closing C# ASP.Net MVC4 Application with a Close Button

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am going to ask the dumnest question ever. I am creating a C# ASP.Net MVC4 application. I want a button on the index page that will shut the application down and close the browser. How do I do it? I currently have the following code snippet in my Index.cshtml to give a button:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CloseApplication", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input id="close" name="closeButton" type="submit" style="width:170px" value="Close Application" />
}
```

I am going to a CloseApplication ActionResult method in my HomeController.cs which currently looks like:

```
public ViewResult    CloseApplication()
{
    // Something to do here I think
    return null;
}
```

What do I do here?

Am I over complicating things?

Many thanks to all of you who contribute regularly and help us out.

Comment: what do you mean by shut the application down and close the browser?! you can close the browser by using javascript easily, not requiring a postback to the controller. but what do you mean shut the application down?!

Comment: By that I mean closing any database connections which is normally done by the Dispose function in the HomeController. If javascript will easily close the browser, may I have a little code snippet please and where to put it? New to all this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly think you are over-complicating things for yourself.

HTTP is stateless so by the time you have rendered a page onto the client's browser, your connections, etc, should have already been `Dispose`'d and the instance of the controller that returned the view the client is now looking at should no longer exist. The next request the client makes will spin up a whole other controller instance.

So the user can already "close" their "instance" (from their perspective) of the application by closing their browser - adding a button to do this is kind of pointless IMHO!

Comment: Thank you. I think I will stop using a "Close" button for this then.